# Question about poles of the Lerch Transcendent

Tags: singularity, zeta-functions, reference-works

The [Lerch Transcendent](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/) is defined as the analytic continutation of the sum
$$
\Phi(z,s,a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+a)^{-s}z^k.
$$
According to [Wolfram functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/04/03/03/01/), for fixed $s$, $a$, the function $\Phi(z,s,a)$ has no poles or essential singularities. But consider,
$$
\Phi(z,-1,1)=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2},
$$
which clearly has a pole at $z=1$.  Is the information on the Wolfram functions site incorrect or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Maple documentation](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LerchPhi):

- If $v$ and $a$ are positive integers, $\Phi(z, a, v)$ has a branch cut in the $z$-plane along the real axis to the right of $z=1$, with a branch point at $z=1$.
- If $a$ is a non-positive integer, $\Phi(z, a, v)$ is a rational function of $z$ with a pole of order $1−a$ at $z=1$.

It doesn't say what happens for non-integer $a$, but I suspect a branch point at $z=1$.